# Deploy Flask application in server

Tags: python, flask, deployment, server

I need to deploy Flask application. It is a education institute management system. **every day 5,000 users** are using this app. I want to deploy this app with **low cost**. what are the options do you suggestion to me to deploy this app ?  What service do you recommond?

suggestions and recommendation